# A question on altering a definition of matrix norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, convex-analysis, matrix-norms

In the definition of the matrix norm, we have
$$\|A\|=\!\!\sup_{\substack{x\in \mathbb{R}^n\\ ||x||=1}} \!\! \|Ax\|$$
I was wondering if we can replace the condition $\|x\|=1$ with $\|x\|\leq 1$. Will the two conditions give the same definition? If so, then why are we not considering the latter one as it will also give us a convex set along with being compact. Since I am new to norms, I would request you to please suggest to me some good books that can make my concepts clear.
Thank you.

Comment: For what it's worth, oftentimes we see an equivalent definition:

$$\| A\| = \max_{\bf{x} \ne 0} \frac{\|A \bf x\|}{\|\bf x\|}$$

This is over a very general set of vectors $\bf{x}$, all nonzero ones. (Your condition probably wouldn't work then because of the zero vector - but at the same time, including the zero vector for your definition would just result in a norm of zero anyways, so it wouldn't really "break" anything.) Your condition thus would work as well, I'm just not sure what it'd actually achieve or do for you.

Comment: Yes, $\lVert A\rVert:=\sup_{\lVert x\rVert=1}\lVert Ax\rVert=\sup_{\lVert x\rVert\leq 1}\lVert Ax\rVert=\sup_{x\neq 0}\lVert Ax\rVert/\lVert x\rVert$ and this coincides with $\operatorname{Lip}A$.  Choose whichever you like (and in $\mathbb{R}^n$ you can use to $\max$ instead of $\sup$).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by homogeneity of the norm, you get the same definition (homogeneity: $\| t x\| = t\|x\|.$)